# Convert Scala's Any type to Date

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark

I have a DF which contains Date columns. I do the following to extract one of them:

```
df.agg(min(substring($"nom_fic", 17, 10))).first.get(0) // gives a variable whith type Any
```

How can I do to convert it to Date type? I tried:

```
dtmin = df.agg(min(substring($"nom_fic", 17, 10))).first.get(0).asInstanceOf[Date]
```

and it returns:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Spark >= 2.2 to_timestamp can be used as shown below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.to_timestamp

scala> df.show(10)
+-------------------+
|                dts|
+-------------------+
|11/26/2019 01:01:01|
|11/20/2019 01:01:01|
+-------------------+

val new_df = df.withColumn("ts", ts).show(2, false)

scala> new_df.show(10)
+-------------------+-------------------+
|                dts|                 ts|
+-------------------+-------------------+
|11/26/2019 01:01:01|2019-11-26 01:01:01|
|11/20/2019 01:01:01|2019-11-20 01:01:01|
+-------------------+-------------------+

scala> val min_val = new_df.agg(min("ts")).first.get(0)
min_val: Any = 2019-11-20 01:01:01.0

scala> val max_val = new_df.agg(max("ts")).first.get(0)
max_val: Any = 2019-11-26 01:01:01.0
```

Comment: What if i want to extract the timestamp and use it in my code

Comment: You can use `ts` in your code which is in timestamp format.

Comment: I tried that. ts is of type org.apache.spark.sql.Column. I only need a single value from that column

Comment: Can you give a small example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: In the DF that you use in your answer. Consider I have multiple timestamps in String format. I would like to get the min of these timestamps (val min = ... ) and the max one (val max = ...) and then use min and max as DATE variables (I would like to insert them in an Oracle table for example. My question is how can I extract these timestamps from the DF and transform them to Date type

Comment: I have updated my answer. If this works, please do accept the answer